# Image is not displayed in the imageview on giving the path of that image

Tags: android, image

I am trying to display image on ImageView. I have the image in `/storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/SAMPLE IMAGES/xxx.png` I have used the following code to display image on the ImageView.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{  Button button,hi,addpic;

final adapter info = new adapter(this);


Runnable m_handlertask = null ;

String path,birth; 

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    hi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    final adapter info = new adapter(this);
 /*   for(int i =1;i<=info.getrowcount();i++)
    {
        java.lang.String[] images_paths = {};
        images_paths[i-1]=info.fetchsingles(i);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), images_paths[i-1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }*/
    hi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,newlist.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    addpic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    addpic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,adpic.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,padd.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
    });
    Date date = new Date(0);
    java.text.DateFormat dateFormat =
        android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());

    dateFormat.format(date);
    final ImageView jpgView;
    jpgView  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    //adapter mDbAdapter;   

//  path = info.getpath(y);
    path = info.getPath();
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    m_handlertask = new Runnable(){ 

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mHandler.postDelayed(m_handlertask,3000);
        condition(); 
        } 
        int i=3;  
        private void condition() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if((i % 3 )== 0) //running 1 time
            {
                birthday();
                    i++;
        }
            else //running 2 times
            { 
                 images();

                i++;
            }
        }
        private void birthday() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
                birth = info.getBirth();  
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is b'day pic : "+birth, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(birth);
        //jpgView.setImageDrawable(d);

         File sdCardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
         Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdCardPath+"/DCIM/Camera/SAMPLE IMAGES/"+path);
         jpgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    //  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(birth);
      //        jpgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
     }
            catch(NullPointerException er) 
           { 
                    String ht=er.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ht, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
private void images() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
                     path = info.getPath(); 
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is reg pic : "+path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(path);
                    // jpgView.setImageDrawable(d);
                     File sdCardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdCardPath+"/DCIM/Camera/SAMPLE IMAGES/"+path);
                     jpgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                //    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                //    jpgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
      }
            catch(NullPointerException er) 
           {
                    String ht=er.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ht, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
m_handlertask.run();
    }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
} }
```

I have read other questions and tutorials, but I found same method of displaying, as I did in the code above. No image is displayed here. I did not find any error message in logcat. Please suggest me, any improvements in the code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you given permission to read external storage in your android manifest?

Comment: yes @GirishGowda, I have given both read and write permissions to the external storage.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space between `"/storage/ sdcard/"`. You should print the stacktrace to see the `Exception` using `er.printStackTrace()`. Also, you shouldn't hardcode the string path; use the `Environment` `Class` to reference file locations in a consistent way.

Comment: sorry @Emmanuel, that space was mistyped in the question. But that's not the problem. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: I have used the Environment class also @Emmanuel. But also I am getting the same problem. Please see the updated code in the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure you have given permission to read external storage in your android manifest file.

2)
instead of hard coding the path to external storage use this.

```
File sdCardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

then add your folder and file name..

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdCardPath+"/DCIM/Camera/img_folder/xxx.png");
                         jpgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Thank you @Girish Gowda for your answer. I have tried your solution. But, there's no change in the output. Is there any other way to displaying the image, otherthan bitmap?

Comment: I also have permissions to read and write to external storage in my manifest file.

Comment: then it might be problem out of that function.. it would be great if you provide full code..

Comment: ok @Girish Gowda, I have updated my question with the complete code.